# Error while fetching values from SQLITE DB

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite database from where I need to fetch some values. I need to fetch the latitude and longitude to put a geopoint on a map but I am getting an error. Here is my logcat:

```
05-07 14:17:52.811 10811-10811/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.disasternew, PID: 10811
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT shelter_id, title, desc, lat, long, route, capacity, current_load FROM Shelter WHERE SELECT title,desc,lat,long,route,capacity,current_load from Shelter
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1346)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1193)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1064)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1270)
       at com.disasternew.MainActivity.doSearch(MainActivity.java:117)
       at com.disasternew.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:93)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Query code:

```
String querySelect = "SELECT title,desc,lat,long,route,capacity,current_load from Shelter";
Log.e("test", "-----" + querySelect);
Cursor locationCursor = database.query("Shelter", new String[]{"shelter_id","title", "desc", "lat", "long","route","capacity","current_load"},querySelect, null, null,
        null, null, null);
locationCursor.moveToFirst();
Log.e("test", querySelect);
while (locationCursor.moveToNext()) {
    String title = locationCursor.getString(locationCursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
    String desc = locationCursor.getString(locationCursor.getColumnIndex("desc"));
    lattitude_shelter = (int) (locationCursor.getFloat(locationCursor.getColumnIndex("lat")) * 1E6);
    longitude_shelter = (int) (locationCursor.getFloat(locationCursor.getColumnIndex("long")) * 1E6);
}
```

Table creation:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_SHELTER_TABLE = "Create table Shelter("+
            " shelter_id INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "+
            " title TEXT ,"+
            " desc TEXT, "+
            " lat Float,"+
            " long Float ,"+
            " route TEXT ,"+
            " capacity INT,"+
            " current_load INT)";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_SHELTER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(" INSERT INTO Shelter VALUES(1,'College More','Salt Lake',22.57,88.43,'Open',10,5);");
    db.execSQL(" INSERT INTO Shelter VALUES(2,'Salt Lake Stadium','Salt Lake',22.56,88.40,'Open',10,8);");
    db.execSQL(" INSERT INTO Shelter VALUES(3,'College More','Salt Lake',22.56,88.40,'Full',10,10);");
}
```

Comment: I guess your `querySelect` is wrong. The third argument of `query` method must be a WHERE clause (without the WHERE itself), where you define which rows should be returned and why. For example, you say: Give me all rows where title is College More. Then it is something like this: `String whereClause = "title = ?"` and then pass the value you are searching inside the args: `String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
    "College More"}`

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I am not using a where clause here.I want all the rows without any filtration and the method that is being used from the inbuilt SQLITEDatabase.class is    public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

Comment: @Opiatefuchs  I also tried rawquery and then it shows"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: lat (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT title,desc,lat,long,route,capacity,current_load FROM Shelter"

Comment: I guess you have make some tries with your app before and then changed something in the database/table structure. You have to delete your app from device, clean project and then reinstall.....

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem, if first line you selected "title,desc,lat,long,route,capacity,current_load" but in query you added "shelter_id":

```
String querySelect = "SELECT title,desc,lat,long,route,capacity,current_load from Shelter";

    Log.e("test", "-----" + querySelect);
    Cursor locationCursor = database.query("Shelter", new String[]{"shelter_id","title", "desc", "lat", "long","route","capacity","current_load"},querySelect, null, null,
```

So please add "shelter_id" to querySelect and try again! :)

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Hi all .thanks for ur help but I already sorted the issue.What I did is just breaking the select statement in different strings and concatening and it worked.Maybe it was some bracket or comma issue.Thanks everybody

Comment: @PayalGarg nice! have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for ur help but I already sorted the issue.What I did is just breaking the select statement in different strings and concatening and it worked.Maybe it was some bracket or comma issue.Thanks everybody